# display from database

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_wines` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_wines_attrib` 
ON `tbl_wines`.`intWinesID` = `tbl_wines_attrib`.`intWinesID` 
AND `tbl_wines_attrib`.`intAttributeValueId` = 4 
WHERE `intStatus` = 1 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I need to know if this query is correct. But am getting all the values from `tbl_wines` not only the value where `intAttributeValueId = 4`.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that condition has been placed as part of your `JOIN` rather than a `WHERE` condition. Instead try the following, moving `tbl_wines_attrib.intAttributeValueId =4`into the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_wines` LEFT JOIN `tbl_wines_attrib` ON `tbl_wines`.`intWinesID` = `tbl_wines_attrib`.`intWinesID` WHERE `tbl_wines_attrib`.`intAttributeValueId` = 4 AND `intStatus` =1 LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: This should work, but I belive you can get rid of the first AND after the JOIN, just use the WHERE clause and the second AND.

Comment: @Scott's Oasys ya you were correct. thank you so much. i got what i need